# Is this digitally created ESA image of a Mars landscape incorrect to what the human eye would see?

Tags: mars, imaging, insight, esa, color

This [ESA image](http://www.esa.int/ESA_Multimedia/Images/2016/01/Perspective_view_in_Noctis_Labyrinthus) below of Noctis Labyrithus was created with data obtained from the High-Resolution Stereo Camera (HRSC), onboard ESA’s Mars Express, seems to depict a time near either sunrise or sunset. The quality of the light indicated suggests what one would see on Earth during the [Golden Hour](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/16028/what-is-golden-hour), warm light with longer shadows.

[image]

I'm assuming NASA's Insight image and gif below suggest the landscape at sunrise or sunset would appear cooler, and the ESA image is not an accurate depiction.

[image]
Included in the gif is "...are the 'raw' versions of the image and the color-corrected version; it's easier to see some details in the raw version, but the latter more accurately shows the image as the human eye would see it."  In either case, the raw or color-corrected version, there appears a cooler color cast across the image.

[Full gif here](https://photojournal.jpl.nasa.gov/archive/PIA23180_cc.gif)

Had the ESA made any mention of the color choice of this rendering?

Comment: To me those shadows look like the sun is around 30-60 degrees, is it possible you've allowed the colour to suggest dawn/dusk to you?

Comment: This may be more appropriate on Photography.SE. What is "true" to the eye is a subject of a lot of debate and it's not just about space imagery.

Comment: The image you have appears to have been created from [these images](http://www.esa.int/Science_Exploration/Space_Science/Mars_Express/Martian_labyrinth) I've not found information on how the four colour filters are used to create a colour image.

Comment: But from [these details](http://www.esa.int/Science_Exploration/Space_Science/Mars_Express/Behind_the_lens) I'd assume it's just a standard RGB mashup

Comment: I accept the possibility of the color influencing me. I hadn't taken a close look at the angle of the shadows.  I was also focusing on the intensity of the light. The shadows did not seem as harsh as a 9am-3pm photograph.  The landscape depicted is Noctis Labyrithus, which is 6° south of Mars equator.  I checking right now for comparisons of the angle of sunlight on Earth at the equator both near the equinox and the solstice. I'm beginning to think this is a fool's errand if those rendering the image didn't take into account the season, and the quality of light.

Comment: The picture appears to be taken looking North, with the sun shining from the West. The shadows are those present in the orignal "photo" of the terrain, at 10m/pixel the edges are probably going to be a bit blurred. If the picture were taken near sunset, the shadows would stretch across to near the top of the next ridge

Comment: In the link you provided above I have reason to believe the right side of the three repeated images is north. Check out -6° 265°on this map planetarynames.wr.usgs.gov/Feature/4324?__fsk=-59356765. In terms of the shadows I was more interested in the detail that can be seen in the shadows, even when the reflected light seemed relatively bright, suggesting to me the sunlight was not as intense as it would be midday, when details would be lost in the shadows.  This is all assuming a standard photograph, which I trust it is not.

Comment: As indicated by the arrow with "N" pointing right at the bottom right, the images birds-eye images are shown with North to the right. The synthesised perspective image, however, is taken viewing north. The corners correspond to -5.35, 244.12 as the upper left; -5.21, 264,89 as the upper right, -7.12, 264.01 as the lower left and -7.14,264.58 as the lower right

Comment: I've rotated and marked the area [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mdIf.jpg) The "aerial" photograph is a relatively standard RGB image, with an exposure that gives a reasonable range. The shadows seem to contain an equivalent amount of detail as earthbound images taken with the sin at a similar angle -- at least as far as google image search for "11am shadows" goes